# Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'page'

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom class for UICollectionViewCell, but I am Unable to access a property in it called page in the ViewController.
**What I have done :**

1) I have created a property called page which is of type Page.

2) I have added custom class to the cell.

[image: image of custom class]

[image: image of inspector]

[image: image of method in viewController]

Comment: Please post code, not pictures. You have to force cast the cell to the custom class (`as!`)

Comment: where should I force cast Im a newbie to ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about type force casting `cell` to `PageCellCollectionViewCell` using `as!`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
"cellID", for: indexPath) as! PageCellCollectionViewCell
    let page = pages[indexPath.item]
    cell.page = page
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks For the answer it helped me

Comment: @vadian also helped you too :)